# Best way to delete a branch in git, so I can recover it

Tags: git

In svn, I would often delete branches which contained work I was no longer interested in, safe in the knowledge I could recover them at any future time if I ever really needed to.

In git, it seems this is impossible. This means I now have about 50 branches or so in 'git branch -a', which I do not expect to ever use again, but do not want to lose them forever.

Is there really no way in git of deleting a branch in a version controlled way? Without sounding anti-git, why is git designed so it is almost required (it seems to me) to throw away old branches in such a way they cannot be recovered? Doesn't this go against the idea of version control.

Comment: http://www.programblings.com/2008/06/07/the-illustrated-guide-to-recovering-lost-commits-with-git/

Comment: I wouldn't throw them away anyway. Whats the matter in just keeping them?

Comment: KingCrunch: Well, I don't really want to throw them away, but 'git branch -a' currently fills more than a screen, which is annoying when I'm trying to remember the names of branches I'm actually working on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is simply renaming "dead" branches, possibly in conjunction with "namespacing" them. For example, if I don't need the branch `topicbranch42` anymore, but I might need it in the future for reference, just do this:

```
git checkout master # or any other branch that isn't topicbranch42
git branch -m topicbranch42 deprecated/topicbranch42
```

That way, you keep all the branches around, but their names provide a pretty clear indicator they're not in active development/use

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to create a tag for the branch you want to archive and then you can delete the branch.

`git tag -a <tagname> <branchname>`

Then, if you ever want to recover the branch you can create a new branch from the tag.

`git checkout -b <branchname> <tagname>`

It might also help to develop a naming scheme for the tags so that all of your archived branch tags are together and at the top or bottom of the tag list.

Comment: seems to me the cleanest of all solutions. It gets it out of git branch -a and leaves them accessible. Better than the renaming into some special namespace since that sill requires you to filter the git branch listing. Excellent

Answer (score 3):

One thing I do sometimes is to rename branches with a prefix:

```
git branch -m foo old/foo
```

Another thing you can do is push the branches you want to save to another bare Git repository for safekeeping, and then delete them in your local repo:

```
git remote add archive /path/to/archive/repo.git
git push archive foo
git branch -D foo
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a ref to the branch head that is outside of the normal namespaces that git uses. This would prevent `git branch` from listing the branch, but would ensure that the commits for that branch are not garbage collected and would still provide a name to get back that branch if you later decide that you actually want it.

```
git update-ref refs/attic/old_topic_branch old_topic_branch
git branch -D old_topic_branch
```

Branches in this attic space could be listed with:

```
git for-each-ref refs/attic
```

And a branch could be recovered with:

```
git checkout -b old_topic_branch refs/attic/old_topic_branch
```

But you would still need to be careful to move those refs to a new repository if you plan to abandon your old repository at any point (such as moving to a new computer), since these refs would not be copied over when cloning the repository.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but I'm afraid looks a bit complicated for me. I'm going to go for just renaming, and then filtering manually. Would be nice if git gained a built-in 'attic'

Answer (score 0):

I just this morning realized the right answer to this:

everything under .git/refs is a reference and so won't be pruned, but only refs/heads are branches, refs/tags are tags, etc.  So just shunt the branch off to an "archive" refs dir.
The really brute-force method is to just `mkdir -p .git/refs/archive/heads; mv .git/refs{,/archive}/heads/master` which will stomp on any previously-archived version of that branch; here's a more thorough version:

```
#!/bin/sh
# archive a branch, by committing it to .git/refs/archive/heads/
# to unarchive the branch, say 'git branch mybranch archive/heads/mybranch~'
# ---- NOIICE the parent link in the branch command above ----------------/
# any second parent of the archive ref is the previous archive header commit

getopts x x && set -x -v && shift

while test $# -ne 0; do
    branch="refs/heads/$1"
    archive="refs/archive/heads/$1"
    git rev-parse -q --verify "$branch" >&- \
    || { echo >&2 archive-branch ignored nonexistent branch: $1; shift; continue; }
    previously=`git rev-parse -q --verify "$archive"`
    git mktree </dev/null | xargs git commit-tree \
        -p "`git rev-parse "$branch"`" \
        ${previously:+ -p $previously} \
        -m "Parent is the archived tip of branch '$1'" \
        ${previously:+ -m 'Second parent is the previous commit like this one.'} \
    > "`git rev-parse --git-dir`/$archive"
    rm "`git rev-parse --git-dir`/$branch"
    shift
done
```

Comment: That seems roughly the same as [the earlier answer by qqx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13481290/98528), no? This seems to have a cool advantage of nice "hiding", but two unfortunate usability disadvantages: first, difficult listing; second, that the refs won't get copied on `git clone`, and thus can be lost accidentally at some point in future. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @akavel The underlying mechanism is the same, of course, but I think you might have missed that `NOTICE` label on the line pointing out the payload here, allowing multiple tracked and recorded archive points of a branch without polluting the namespace.

Comment: @akavel So far as the disadvantages go, the complaint was the number of names showing up on `git branch -a`.  Only options I can see are make new refs that aren't branches, move the refs to a separate archive repo, or do what OP eventually accepted, rename to branches that still show up but off to one side so they can be ignored as a group.  All three have their disadvantages, but note that you can fetch any ref you want from a repo, the refspec notation is very flexible. You can even do a mass local rename using $PWD as the repo:  `git fetch $PWD refs/archives/heads/*:refs/heads/archives/*`

Answer (score -1):

Deleting a git branch just deletes a label that refers to a commit.
You can run `git checkout <commit-hash>` to recover the deleted branch, as long as you write down the hash somewhere.

Running `git gc` will permanently delete these orphaned commits.

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer my question -- if git gcs by itself at some point, I won't be able to get back my old branches.

Comment: @ChrisJefferson As SLaks said: "Deleting a git branch just deletes a label". This means, that you'll get back the branch, when you create a branch with the old name to the old commit. Thats it :)

Comment: @KingCrunch no, Chris is correct in that it isn't safe to remove the reference to a branch that you want to keep around. Git does do automatic garbage collection and at some point branches which don't have any references (labels) pointing to them will be removed from the object store.

Comment: @qqx I don't know the details, but git doesn't remove commits "at will", because you can always checkout them by their SHA-hash. Especially the "normal" gc-run doesn't delete them.

Comment: @KingCrunch Normally, even if the only branch that refers to a commit is deleted there will still be a reference to that in the reflog for `HEAD`. But entries in the reflog eventually expire (90 days by default), and once that happens those commits would be eligible for garbage collection. So it won't happen for some time, but it will eventually.